# Ожидание прогрузки всех компонентов React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hook

Есть компонент LoadingScreen - который представляет из себя лоадер
Мне нужно его скрывать в тот момент, когда прогрузятся остальные компоненты этой страницы
Пробую через хук useState, но не могу подобрать условия для изменения стейта isLoading

```js
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    // Какое-то условие, чтобы изменить isLoading на false
      setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <>
      {isLoading
      ? <LoadingScreen /
      : //Компоненты страницы
      }
    </>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, что значит компоненты главной страницы? Если вы пользуетесь  use-router,  тогда главная страница - это путь / , но он является компонентом тоже.

Comment: Прошу прощения за такую формулировку, имелись ввиду компоненты той же страницы, на которой находится лоадер (поправил описание)

Answer (score 0):

[Документация](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) говорит:

> Не забывайте, что React откладывает выполнение useEffect, пока браузер не отрисует все изменения,...

То есть вам нет необходимости добавлять какое то условие. Работает так:

- Рендерит
- Выполняет `useEffect()` один раз и оставляет `isLoading == false` до конца жизненного цикла (поскольку используется конструкция с пустым массивом)
- Снова рендерит уже относительно нового значения `isLoading`